# Scaling objects based on variables

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay so what I'm attempting to do is have a rectangle track my over all speed.
What I would like to do is have it so it either fills in based on my speed or shrink and grow based on my speed. I have in my small "game" a maxSpeedConstant as well as a newMaxSpeedConstant (when he's running) all my code works fine, I just can't figure out how to track my speed with the 2 variables. The newMaxSpeedConstant is ONLY used if shift and a movement key is pressed. I also would like to scale my speed too! Meaning, I have my maxSpeedConstant at 10 and my newMaxSpeedConstant at 40. Rather than hitting shift and immediately jumping to 40 pix. I'd rather him slowly start to "run". Sorry for these probably silly questions. Just trying a bunch of small things so I can eventually do something big! Thanks for any and all help! I am a noob so again sorry if this seems easy. Also not sure if seeing my code would help or not so just let me know if you would need it and how much of it!

Comment: I recommend a book by Keith Peters, Foundation Actionscript 3.0 Animation: Making Things Move!, the earlier chapters cover what you need. Right now this question is too broad and will likely be deleted or closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece you're missing in your calculations is time.  You can either change values over a fixed amount of time, or change the values over time until they reach a desired limit.

For example, to change speed over a fixed number of frames (time), you might:

(executed once when the user presses the "go" or "stop" control...)

```
var changeInSpeedEachFrame:Number = (finalSpeed - currentSpeed) / numberOfFramesToAccelerate;
```

(...and this is executed each frame...)

```
if ( changeInSpeedEachFrame != 0 )
{
    currentSpeed += changeInSpeedEachFrame;
    if ( currentSpeed == finalSpeed )
    {
        changeInSpeedEachFrame = 0;
    }
}
```

This will work for acceleration and deceleration.  If your finalSpeed is less than your currentSpeed, then changeInSpeedEachFrame will be negative.

Note that the userSpeed == finalSpeed test can go awry with the Number class, since Numbers are floating point and can be imprecise.  Depending on your situation, you might use an int instead, or check if you've gone slower or faster than your limits.